# How to convert a json object to a string in a alert box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to debug my response (json) and have it displaying as a string in a alert box. Are there any convenient thing to do?

```
var myjson = { Name : "Marko" }; 

alert(myjson.toString()); // ? [Object] !!!
```

Comment: @casperOne "not a real question". Come on! Great Q marko.

Comment: @oma No, it's not.  It shows no original research effort (which is "not a real question") and is also "not constructive" (what is convenient is subjective).  That said, the *answers* are fine, but that doesn't make the question good.  The question lacks quality from the Stack Overflow perspective.

Comment: I think it is a valid question from a programmers point of view! And the question is specific.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most convenient way, would be using the console of your browser.

```
console.log(json);
```

In most browsers you get a very clearly view of the json contents.

Alternativly you could make a string with a for-loop:

```
var output = '';
for (var entry in json) {
  output += 'key: ' + entry + ' | value: ' + json[entry] + '\n';
}
alert(output);
```

But this is not recursively. Here is a working demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/n695V/

Comment: If you have two objects, which the first is a object and the later one is a array of objects, this solution does not work so well. And I'm working on a remote Windows Server which has only IE9.

Answer (score 19):

you can use the following on your success response:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use JSON.stringify. However, I don't know if it works in all common browsers.

alert(JSON.stringify(json-object));

Comment: Depending on browser you may need to include this on your page to make JSON.stringify work https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Answer (score 2):

You can analyze the response text of a request with Firebug or Google Chrome built-in console.

Answer (score 1):

You will get the clear answer, if you provide the JSON structure.

For example, if you have below JSON structure.

```
  var json={ “id”:23,”name”:”marko”};
    for(key in json){
            alert(key+'->'+json[key]);
     }
```

It's not simple for above single node json. If JSON structure is deeper, you need to iterate till you get value :)

Or. Rather easiest way is do console.log(json); and see in firebug, you will get what is inside json block.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(myObject, replacer);
```

A JSON stringifier goes in the opposite direction, converting JavaScript data structures into JSON text. JSON does not support cyclic data structures, so be careful to not give cyclical structures to the JSON stringifier. http://www.json.org/js.html

Answer (score 0):

```
function JSON2string (jsonobject,prefix) {
  if (!prefix) prefix="";
  if (typeof(jsonobject)=="string") return jsonobject;
  if (typeof(jsonobject)=="number") return jsonobject.toString();
  if (typeof(jsonobject)=="object") {
    var s="Object:\n"
    var newprefix="  "+prefix;
    for (var i in jsonobject) s+=prefix+i+"="+JSON2String(jsonobject[i],newprefix)+"\n";
    return s;
  }
  return "<unhandled>";
}
```