# asp.net Ajax submit event displays the json result returned from controller instead of alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

i have a view which contains javascript code to submit data to the controller

The Data is processed successfully at the controller however the page display the json result returned from controller instead of alert. any idea ?

here is my code

```
<code>
@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{  
 //some thing

<input id="btSaveDetails" type="submit" name="btnSave" value="Save" />

}

javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btSaveDetails").submit(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            url: '@Url.Action("Groups", "User")',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response.Status);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (errorThrown == "Forbidden") {
                    alert("Forbidden access");
                } else {
                    alert('An error occurred please retry.');
                }
            }
        });
    });

</script>

controller :
     public JsonResult Groups(GroupsModel userGroups)
        {
//some processing 
return Json(new { Status = "Saved" });
}
</code>
```

Thanks

Comment: The form is submitted, there is nothing that prevents the default submit

Comment: Try changing input type to "button" instead of "submit" to prevent default form submission or in submit function prevent default event like e.preventDefault() and return false

Comment: Thanks guys...its fixed !!
Changed input type to "button"

Answer (score 0):

I changed the html.beginform helper as follows,

please try this and let me know.

```
<pre> <code><script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script> @using (@Html.BeginForm("Groups", "User")) {   
<input type="text" /> <input id="btSaveDetails" type="submit" name="btnSave" value="Save" /> }  <script type="text/javascript">
$("#btSaveDetails").submit(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        url: '@Url.Action("Groups", "User")',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response.Status);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (errorThrown == "Forbidden") {
                alert("Forbidden access");
            } else {
                alert('An error occurred please retry.');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and you also modified the success response as follows

[How to convert a json object to a string in a alert box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895138/how-to-convert-a-json-object-to-a-string-in-a-alert-box)